# Is declaring a class in C++ as "final : public virtual" EVER useful?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual, final, virtual-inheritance

When declaring a c++ class as final, is it ever needed to inherit base classes using virtual inheritance? I know what virtual inheritance is for and use it to avoid member duplication.

As an example, if I have these class definitions (imagine all of them having some members and virtual deconstructors)

```
class B : public virtual A {};
class C : public virtual A {};
class D : public virtual C {};
```

Does it make sense to define a next class as

```
class E final : public virtual D {}
```

or

```
class F final : public virtual B, public virtual C {};
```

or is the default inheritance, i.e.

```
class E final : public D {}
class F final : public B, public C {};
```

**always** enough?

This has bothered me for a long time now, as I see from time to time code, that includes

```
"final : public virtual"
```

Could the `virtual` be safely omitted here in **any** case?

Any hints/explanations are greatly appreciated

Comment: Since virtual inheritance allows the base class to be shared (i.e., only have once instance), and final is used to mark a class as not being allowed to be derived from... those two things are independent of one another.  If you remove the virtual, the base class is no longer being shared.  Only of concern for multiple inheritance.

Comment: Could you provide a (multiple inheritance) example where omitting the `virtual` really makes a difference?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance has an example.   Imagine `struct Bat final : Mammal, WingedAnimal, virtual Animal` being changed to `struct Bat final : Mammal, WingedAnimal, Animal` ... whoops, bat.eat() became ambiguous.

Comment: @Eljay "_Only of concern for multiple inheritance._" Not exactly. Virtual blurs the distinction between direct and indirect base class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct A { void foo() { cout << "foo" << endl; } };
struct B : virtual A {};
struct D final : virtual A, B {};

D d;
d.foo();
```

Without `virtual` before `A` call to `foo` would be ambiguous.

Comment: Perfect. That means that the virtual could **always** be ommited when **not** using multiple inheritance?

Comment: @Ironbell yes, `virtual` in this context was added exactly to handle diamond problem.

Comment: @Ironbell • I never found a need for multiple inheritance of concrete base classes or abstract base classes in the production C++ code I've worked on.  I have used multiple inheritance for having one-and-only-one concrete-or-abstract base class, and multiple interface classes.  (C++ doesn't enforce the constraint by having an `interface` keyword, so it is only by convention and discipline.)

Comment: @Eljay It was not a question about whether and when to use MI, but whether this combination was ever useful. For MI, well, one size does not fit them all. Thanks for your answers, I sadly do not have enough rep yet to upvote comments.

Comment: "_call to foo would be ambiguous_" Not only that that (remark not applicable to your simple example where `A` has no state and no constructor that does much) **without virtual, you cannot even write a constructor that initializes either base class subobject `A`**